# Determine if the following subspace is dense

Tags: power-series, hilbert-spaces, dense-subspaces

Let $H$ be a (separable) Hilbert space, and let $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis. Define the following function
\begin{align*}
\phi:\mathbb{C}&\to H\\ z&\mapsto \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{z^n}{n!}e_n
\end{align*}

> Show that $\phi$ is well-defined, i.e. show that $\phi(z)\in H$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

This part I feel pretty good about. We can estimate the norm by
\begin{align*}
\| \phi(z) \|^2&=\left\| \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{z^n}{n!}e_n \right\|^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{|z|^{2n}}{n!^2}\leq e^{2|z|}<\infty
\end{align*}

> Let $S=\text{span}\{\phi(z)\mid z\in\mathbb{C}\}$ be the set of all finite linear combinations of elements in the image of $\phi$. Either show that $S\leq H$ is dense or find a non-zero $v\in S^\perp$.

My intuition is that $S$ is dense, and that I should use the strategy of showing that $S^\perp=\{0\}$. Here's what I tried:

Suppose $v=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}v_ne_n\in S^\perp$. Then $0=\langle v,\phi(0)\rangle=v_0$. To try to show the other coefficients are zero, I noticed that the expansion of $(e^z-1)^N$ gives a way to find a vector  $\omega^N\in S$ such that $\langle \omega^N,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $n<N$. Let me write a vector in sequence notation to illustrate what I mean. For $N=1$, we have
\begin{align*}
e^z-1\Longrightarrow \phi(1)-\phi(0)&=(1,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},\ldots) \\ &-(1,0,0,0,\ldots) \\ &=(0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},\ldots)
\end{align*} For $N=2$, we have $(e^z-1)^2=e^{2z}-2e^{z}+1$ so
\begin{align*}
\phi(2)-2\phi(1)+\phi(0)&=(1,2,2,\frac{4}{3},\ldots ) \\ &-(2,2,1,\frac{1}{3},\ldots) \\ &+(1,0,0,0,0,\ldots) \\ &=(0,0,1,1,\frac{7}{12},\ldots)
\end{align*}

Similarly, $$\omega^N=\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n}\phi(n)=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,\frac{N}{2},\ldots)$$
Now I'm kinda stuck because I'm not sure how to apply the inductive step to show $v_{N+1}=0$. I'm wondering if this isn't at all the right approach... Another idea would be to use identities like $$\frac{\phi(z)+\phi(-z)}{2}=(1,0,\frac{z^2}{2},0,\frac{z^4}{4!},0,\ldots)$$
Similarly we can use an $m^{th}$ root of unity to find a vector in $S$ such that the coefficient $a_m$ on $e_m$ is only non-zero if $n$ divides $m$. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Apply complex analysis methods. The function $f(z)=\langle \phi(z),v\rangle $ is entire. If it vanishes then all its MacLaurin coefficients vanish.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc  Ah, that's a good idea! But could you explain a bit more? How do we conclude that $v=0?$

Comment: The MacLaurin coefficients of $f(z)=\langle \phi(z), v\rangle$ are equal ${1\over n!}\langle e_n,v\rangle.$ If they all vanish then $v=0.$

Comment: That makes sense, I was definitely over-thinking it. Thanks so much!